# Etiquette for proper usage of Greek letters and other notation

Tags: soft-question, notation

I've progressed to the "output" point in my mathematics career and have run into a slightly embarrassing problem while writing a paper. Clearly, certain Greek letters are suitable for some situations ($\epsilon$ and $\delta$ for small numbers, etc.) but is there any comprehensive etiquette for naming that I should be aware of? It seems like arbitrarily assigning sets and functions Greek letters could be a bit confusing to the reader.

Comment: This article on Wikipedia has a list with every Greek letter and their common utilisation in all sciences, including maths. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_letters_used_in_mathematics,_science,_and_engineering

Comment: Arbitrary selection of names and letters is definitely not the way to go. You may end up with some monster like "Let $X$ be a metric space, let $\gamma,p \in X$ be two points, and let $\Omega$ be the distance between $\gamma$ and $p$". Good stylistic conventions with notation are hard to develop from scratch. You could try, as a first step, copying the style of a paper or book that you admire, and develop it out in a consistent manner from there.

Comment: +1 to Lee Mosher's advice.  Since etiquette is a living thing, I'd add that the admired book should be relatively recent (I'd say written within the last 20-30 years but I welcome corrections to this estimate).  The phrasing of the question suggests a level of thoughtfulness that already bodes well for the OP's writing: this is a skill that will improve greatly as you continue thinking about it while reading and writing papers.